# Not able to post data from react to node.ks empty body `{}`

Tags: node.js, reactjs

What am i doing wrong? Why i am not able to get the image in node.js route? Why result is `{}`

**Node.js Route defined:**

```
   app.post('/form', (req, res) => {
        console.log('/form...');
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

**React Handler to post Data:**

```
      handlePost= (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();

      var formData = new FormData();
          var imagefile = document.getElementById('file1');
          formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
          axios.post('/form', formData, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
          })
      }
```

**React Form to upload Image:**

```
 <div className="container">
   <div className="row">
      <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handlePost} method="post">
         <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="file1">Upload file</label>   
         <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" className="custom-file-input"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

by retrieving by id are you getting a single value, in `formData.append` because you do `imagefile.files[0]` ? it just has to be imagefile:

```
formData.append("image", imagefile);
```